# iMessage "Start New Conversations From" options different on iPad than iPhone

Tags: messages

All of a sudden my iPad sends messages showing an email that I never use. For years it worked the same as my phone. Does anyone know how to correct this? When I go to settings, and click on send and receive on my iPad, it now shows 3 email addresses and not phone number. If I sign out, it will not let me send any messages without signing in, using my Apple ID.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how an iPad could have a phone number... "You can be reached at..." Yes. "Send from..." No.

Comment: @Tetsujin See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201349#ios. You can set up...tethering, for lack of a better word, so that messages sent from non-iPhone devices are sent from the phone number of the iPhone, to maintain continuity.

Answer (score 1):

The setting you are talking about can be found in

> Settings > Messages > Start new conversations from

This will only work if you have signed in with the same Apple ID on both- the iPad and the iPhone.

If you cannot get it to work, try signing out of both devices and signing back in.